# Displaying all repositorys under a remote project

Tags: java, git, jgit

I am trying to display all the repositories under a project, then a user would be able to select one repo and see all the remote branches under that repo. Currently I can show the remote branches of a specific repo by using

```
Collection<Ref> remote = Git.lsRemoteRepository().setRemote("ssh uri of remote").call();
```

But since there are a lot of repos under this project I am looking for a way to not have to hard code in every clone link to show the list of all repos that I am trying to display.

When I try to use a similar method of using `lsRemoteRepository` on the top project repo I get this **error:**

> org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException:
>   http://my/project/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found

Is there a way to list all the repositories under a remote project using jGit?
Most of what I have found is for repos local to your machine. Would there be a way to use the local repo to find the instance of the remote repo?

Any thoughts or tips in the right direction would be appreciated. First time using jGit as well so any best practice tips for accessing remote repos/projects would be appreciated as well.

Comment: There is not, this is not part of the git protocol, which works on _repositories_ and has no knowledge of any higher-level collection of them.  Your hosting provider may have an API that will allow you to do this - eg, GitHub has an API - but we would need to know which hosting provider you are using to help with that information.

Comment: We use stash to host our projects. I found https://developer.atlassian.com/static/javadoc/stash/3.11.3/api/reference/packages.html
as far as API for stash goes and can dig through this. It would seem like from your comment this is my best bet for a solution?